# React: Removing dynamic input from state, rerender

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, slice

I am having trouble debugging this situation. I am attempting to remove an index from an array provided by an API.  I store this in the Parent state after checking for prop change by it's parent.  All is good here.  I can store any prop changes in the Parent Form state.

The Parent Form maps everything in **templateData** and I determine what type it is and then render a component depending.

The remove button will always only be in a **DynamicInputGroup** so I am passing that function down via props.  In the **DynamicInputGroup** I need to map through the array passed from the parent, then map the objects within that array to display each individual input.  Again using props passed down to determine which input to render, same as parent.

**Here is where things go wrong.  When I click remove, let's say index 2 out of 5, I see that index being removed in the state, but what's rendered is index 5 being removed.** I am unsure how to go about this.  I've done research and read that keys come into play?  I've tried to set a variable in the render function to the state so it'll refresh, but nothing. the last index always gets removed.  Halp!

**Parent Form**

```
this.state = {
    templateData: []
}

removeGroupItem = (index, inputName ) => {
    let group = `${inputName}__group`
    const newState = this.state;
    if (index === -1) return;
    newState.templateData[group].splice(index, 1);
    console.log(newState) // THIS SHOWS CORRECT STATE
    this.setState(newState);
}

render() {
    return (
      {Object.keys(this.state.templateData).map((name, key) => {
          let data = { // SETTING inputType TO DISPLAY CORRECT COMPONENT }
          return (
              <Fragment key={key}>
                  {data.inputType == 'input' && <DynamicTextInput {...data} />}
                  {data.inputType == 'rtf' && <DynamicRTF {...data}  />}
                  {data.inputType == 'img' && <DynamicImageUpload {...data} />}
                  {data.inputType == 'group' && <DynamicInputGroup {...data} removeGroupItem={this.removeGroupItem} />} // COMPONENT THAT HOLDS REMOVE BUTTON
              </Fragment>
          )
      })}
    )
}
```

**DynamicInputGroup Componenet**

```
this.state = {
    value: []
}


componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ value: this.props.value })
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.value !== prevProps.value) {
        this.setState({
            value: this.props.value
        })
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Typography>{this.props.inputName}</Typography>
            {this.state.value.map((value, key) => {
                return (
                    <span>
                    {Object.keys(value).map((input, index) => {
                        let data = { // SETTING inputType TO DISPLAY CORRECT COMPONENT }
                        return (
                            <Grid key={index}>
                                {data.inputType == 'input' && <DynamicTextInput {...data} />}
                                {data.inputType == 'rtf' && <DynamicRTF {...data} />}
                                {data.inputType == 'img' && <DynamicImageUpload {...data} />}
                                {data.inputType == 'group' && <DynamicInputGroup {...data} />}
                            </Grid>
                        )
                    })}
                        {key >= 1 ? <span onClick={() => this.props.removeGroupItem(key, this.props.inputName)}>remove</span> : ''}
                    </span>
                )
            })}
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Then, if needed a **DynamicTextInput**

```
const DynamicTextInput = (props) => {
    return (
        <Grid>
            <TextField
                name={props.inputName} label={props.inputName} defaultValue={props.value}
                size="small" variant="outlined" fullWidth multiline
            />
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using index as component's key is a bad practise, especially if it is a list that is changing. Key should be unique identifier of component.

If you don't have unique identifier for your controls, you could create one based on the timestamp, some sort of uuid, that you will store in your state and that will always and always just reference the one control element.

Imagine that you have situation where you have 1 input element that has value of `TextInput 1`. Then you add another input in from of it and it inherits its key. Now you have broken shadow DOM since you are referencing to new input instead of the old one because input with key={0} has value of `TextInput 1`, but that's not what you expect, because you want to refer to another input.

Comment: Trying to think of a unique id to give them.  I was thinking the value of the object, but there could be an instance of non unique values

Comment: @Ryan uuid is a way to go. You can give it key of `input-${Date.now()}` and then you just stick to that key throughout the session. If you need to have this layout/logic persistent you would store that uuid to your db as well.

Comment: And would I set that key to the Grid in DynamicInputGroup ? This is where I am getting confused

Comment: Yes, 1st child in the map function, in your current case that is Grid. Grid's child elements will not have the confusion in reconciliation phase

Comment: Seems moving the remove button into the correct map also solves the issue.  But renaming my keys to unique IDs worked

Comment: Wanted to see if I could get your input again... I've switched to useState hooks, and seem to be running into an issue with the map function not updating.  I see the index being removed in the props being passed down to the component, and each item in the map has a very unique key, but nothing...

Comment: I was actually able to figure it out.  I've been messing with react-final-form, which is imo okay.. prefer redux, but values weren't being passed correctly to the form state therefor not updating properly. Thanks for returning a comment though!

Answer (score 0):

This line has the problem:

```
<Fragment key={key}>
```

Since you are using the index of the array to render those `Fragments`, the reconciliation fails `length` times and the "last element" gets removed. I would really recommend watching [this video](https://youtu.be/b8IcYOV5_Rc), so helpful. You should use an unique identifier.